# Will increasing my computer memory increase my computer's speed?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have copy my computer's details.

**HP Pavilion 17**

- Intel Core i3-4000M CPU 240Ghz 2400Mhz, 2 cores, 4 logic
- 64 Bit
- Windows 10
- 4 GB Ram

If I increase the RAM memory, would this help?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly, it depends on what you are trying to speed up. RAM doesn't universally increase a machine's overall speed. I would say more RAM is most practical for multi-tasking or productivity.

Comment: It depending on what software your trying to use.  If you using notepad or minesweeper adding RAM is pointless.  More RAM only speeds up your system if your running out of it, and that is causing a slow down.

Comment: [check the peak memory usage](https://superuser.com/a/1019786/174557) and if you require more RAM, add more ram to avoid paging otherwise don't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Probably. You can check the memory usage on the Performance tab of Windows Task Manager (to start that, right click on the task bar and select "Start Task Manager").

If you memory usage is high, you'll probably benefit from more memory. While you are there, check your CPU usage. If that's stays high (say above 80%) you probably need a new machine.

Comment: I would consider 4 GB to be a bare minimum for running Windows 10.  Such a system is very likely to have lots of disk swapping going on, so an increase of RAM will almost certainly help the system run faster.

Comment: Memory is @ 93%. CPU is @ 9%.

Comment: You can definitely benefit from more RAM. You should see a significant improvement in performance if you add another 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft official document(Windows 10 system requirements) indicates that, RAM is 2 GB for 64-bit system at least, if Hyper-V is enabled, additional 2 GB of RAM is necessary.

Also, please note the max RAM limit:
[image]

In general, optimizing hardware configuration is helpful at some degree for improving system performance, including RAM expansion as you had mentioned. Also, hardware compatibility should also be considered of the newly added RAM.

At the same time, system performance depends on many factors. Finds out the main factor which affect system performance and improve it, then, it would be more useful.

**Tips to improve PC performance in Windows 10**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4002019/windows-10-improve-pc-performance